# complete multiple texboxes based on dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to add a dropdown to a form with pre-set options. When the user selects an option I would like this to complete 2 separate text boxes according to the dropdown option.

Basic outline:

```
if dropdown value = 1 fill text box 1 with 00:00 and text box 2 with 01:00
if dropdown value = 2 fill tex box 1 with 01:00 and text box 2 with 02:00
```

Hopefully this is clear enough? I know how to set a single text box with the value set for the dropdown option but this isn't right for what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, add a change listener to your select box and update the inputs inside based on your selected value:

```
$(function(){

    $("#select1").on("change",function(){
        var curVal = $(this).val();
        if(curVal == "1"){
            $("#input1").val("00:00");   
            $("#input2").val("01:00");  
        }else if(curVal=="2"){
           $("#input1").val("01:00");   
           $("#input2").val("02:00");  
        }
    });
});
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/iaretyler/zfruguj7/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yhwe2of4/1/)**

```
$("#selectOpt").on('change',function(){
    var value=parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').val());
    $("#txt1").val("0"+(value-1)+":00");
    $("#txt2").val("0"+(value)+":00");
});
```